# How can a user eliminate a repeating field?

Tags: cognito-forms

How can a user eliminate a repeating field entry on a Cognito Form?  For example, I have a repeating field for Registration.  If the user clicks on "add registration" the repeating field is displayed again.  If they want to eliminate a registration, can they?

Answer (score 1):

In order to delete a repeating section entry, all a user needs to do is select the "X" next to the corresponding Item label:

[image]

Comment: of course!  how did I not see that?  thanks!

Comment: @Heidi: If an answer solved your problem, the generally accepted way to thank the poster is to "accept" the answer. It also acts as a signpost for future readers who might have the same issue. More information at [What should I do when someone answers my question?](/help/someone-answers).